# Determine current hour is between hours

Tags: java

I feel this is really easy but my brain isn't working for some reason. I have a feature where the user can select a time period (in hours) for it to run. I need to check if the current hour is between those hours:

```
int currentHour = LocalDateTime.now().getHour(); // 21 (9pm)

int startHour = 20; // (8pm)
int endHour = 1; // (1am)

if (currentHour >= startHour && currentHour < endHour)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Presumably you want to calculate the entire date/time, not *just* the hour.  Because I can't think of any value that's greater than 20 and less than 1.  Or alternatively maybe you meant to use `||` (or) instead of `&&` (and), if the set of hours is always "overnight"?

Comment: LocalDateTime has an isAfter and isBefore Method, maybe this helps you (if you want to compare a whole Date, not only the hour).

Comment: This issue is if the endHour goes into the next day like my example.

Comment: Do you only do time ranges that are strictly <= 24 h long?

Comment: yes, just into the next day. Your response worked. Thanks.

Comment: [`LocalDateTime#getHour()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getHour--) already returns the hour value in 24h format. If it returns 9, that means 9 in the morning – and 9 in the morning is not between 8 in the evening and 1 in the morning.

Comment: By the way, calling `LocalDateTime.now` is a bad habit. The result is inherently ambiguous as it lacks the context of an offset or time zone. Instead, call `ZonedDateTime.now( z )` while passing a time zone (`ZoneId`). To use the JVM’s current time zone, pass result of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. So: `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )`

Comment: My example isn't returning 9. I put "9pm" which means `currentHour` should be set to 21.

Comment: If you want only time of day, call `LocalTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )`. Or pass a specific time zone if you have one in mind.

Comment: In the source code for `LocalDateTime.now` it looks like it takes the timezone into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to account for ranges that cover midnight, e.g.

```
if (endHour < startHour) {
  endHour += 24;
}
if (currentHour < startHour) {
  currentHour += 24;
}

// now check if currentHour between start and end
```

Do note however that [`LocalDateTime#getHour()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getHour--) returns a value between 0 and 23 already. So 9 means 9AM and 21 means 9PM.

Answer (score 0):

The value `9` does not mean the same thing as `9pm` or `21`; it means `9am` or simply `9`.

You need to use `21`.

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimeRangeChecker {
    private static final int HOURS_PER_DAY = (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(1); // 24

    public static boolean isInBetween(LocalDateTime localDateTime, int startHour, int endHour) {
        int computedEndHour = endHour < startHour ? endHour + HOURS_PER_DAY: endHour;
        int currHour = localDateTime.getHour();
        return currHour >= startHour && currHour < computedEndHour;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now().withHour(21); // 9pm
        System.out.println(isInBetween(now, 20, 1)); // false
    }
}
```